# Finding powerseries $\frac{1}{z^2-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me out with finding the powerseries of:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-z}$ about $a=-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=z+1$. Then $z^2-z=z(z-1)=(x-1)(x-2)$, so

$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2-x}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  x^k-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)x^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\bigg)(z+1)^k
$$

Comment: It is $\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x-1}$ - you have a sign problem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews corrected, thanks.

Comment: Still an error in the formula: $\left(\frac x2\right)$ should be $\left(\frac 1 2\right)^k$.

Answer (score 3):

It holds:

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-z} = \frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z}$$

So the powerseries is

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1-2^{-1-n}\right)\left(1+z\right)^n$$

Comment: The "so the power series is...." is a rather huge leap in such a simple question. Perhaps a little further hint...

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe you are right, but I assumed that the powerseries of both appering terms are well-known

Comment: Oh, they indeed are @user127001...yet is it **not** the series of the terms appearing there what you need but of the function as a power series of $\;z+1\;$ ...!

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fractions we have 
$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z-1}-\dfrac{1}{z}$$

$$\begin{align*} 
f(z)&=\dfrac{1}{z-1}-\dfrac{1}{z}\\&=\dfrac{1}{-2+z+1}-\dfrac{1}{-1+(z+1)}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{1-(z+1)/2}+\sum_{n\geq 0}(z+1)^{n}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{-n}(z+1)^{n}+\sum_{n\geq 0}(z+1)^{n}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I got it this time. Sorry for algebra mistakes.

Comment: Nice @TheNumber23...why don't you finally put both bottom series together? +1

Comment: Got lazy I guess. Don't know why.